# Append lines one after another in notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex, find-and-replace

How do we achieve the following using replace function in notepad++?

**Transforming  the following**

```
cow
horse
elephant
camel
```

**into**

```
'cow','horse','elephant','camel'
```

I know ^ and $ (under Regular Expression) will let me access the beginning and end of the line and therefore I can put the single quotes at the extremes but then how do I append the lines thereafter? Also, I want to do everything (putting quotes and appending) in one go if possible.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. [Download the latest version](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v6.1.html), it includes regular expression [fixes](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Replacing_Newlines).
2. Replace using the regular expression: `(.*)[\r\n]*` and turn it into `'\1',`
3. Remove the last `,`, it's not possible to do this inside the regular expression in Notepad++.

Comment: Thanks @Tom . Will you mind explaining a bit on your second step...

Comment: "fixes" link does not work.

Comment: @Stat-R: I guess you figured out because of the replace, but it is basically like this: You go to the "replace" dialog and then tick "Regular Expression" and then fill in the two codes I gave you in the two boxes.

Comment: @TomWijsman: "This page has been deleted"? Well, perhaps it shows that it is no longer an issue since the wiki page is no longer needed, if that is what you mean.

Comment: @DanielAndersson: Now read the whole line under that. :D

Answer (score 2):

This solution is not a 100% percent solution, but it gets you most of the way there and is very simple.  When I want to do this I use the "Extended" search mode on the replace dialog and use `\r\n` as the search term.  In your case you would replace it with `','`.  That will get you to

```
cow','horse','elephant','camel
```

Now you just need to fix the first and last elements manually.

Comment: I tried this before asking my question here but for some reason (??) this did not work for me. I am using NP++(6.1).

Comment: I just tried it on 6.1 and it worked fine.  Make sure you file is using Windows line endings (View->Show Symbol->Show End of Line).  You should see a `CRLF` at the end of each line.  If you just see `LF` change your search term to `\n`.

Comment: I saw `CR` and I used \r. It worked. Thanks @heavyd